# Cytoscape 3.7.2 dosen't install on Mac OSx 10.15.3 even with JDK 8

Tags: java, cytoscape

On a clean new machine with JDK 8 fresh installed, the freshly download Cytoscape .dmg file (v 3.7.2) opens but crashes before installing anything. The install GUI is very slow and doesn't proceed (I need to close it with "Force Quit" from the right-click menu).

The check script seems working fine:

```
Target Cytoscape version: 3.7.2
Your shell is zsh
Compatible OS version found: 10.15
 - Pass: OS Version = 10.15.3
 - Pass: Following Oracle JDK found:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk
 - Pass: Current Java Version = 1.8.0_241
 - Pass: JAVA_HOME found: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_*.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to hear you're having problems!  Can you give us a bit more information?  It sounds like the installer is trying to write files that it doesn't have access to (just a guess).  I'm also running 10.15.3 and I'm not seeing the same problem, so something is definitely amiss.  Three suggestions for you:

1. Submit a bug to the cytoscape bug list
2. Try downloading the tar ball (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape/releases/download/3.7.2/cytoscape-3.7.2.tar.gz) and untar it in /Applications.  Then try to run "cytoscape.sh" in that directory.
3. Upgrade to Java 11 and download Cytoscape 3.8-RC4 from https://cytoscape-builds.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-builds/Cytoscape-3.8.0/3.8.0-Release-Candidate-4/ to see if that works better.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried your third suggestion, and with the new version it works. BTW, the version 3.8 asks me if I want to update to the 3.7.2 :)